# Displaying "level" in a tree output from a proc cluster

Tags: sql, tree, sas

I have a tree I created from a proc cluster, and I would like to add the level for each cluster.

```
_NAME_ _PARENT_   lvl
CL1                 1
CL2     CL1         2
CL3     CL2         3
CL4     CL1         2
CL5     CL4         3
CL6     CL3         4
CL7     CL5         4
CL8     CL6         5
CL9     CL6         5
```

On excel, I just have to do a simple VLookup, but I can't manage to do it on SAS.

Here is the code that I tried:

```
data etude.tree;
    set etude.tree;
    drop Clef;
    if _NAME_='CL1' then level=1;
run;

proc sql;
   create table etude.tree2 as
   select distinct a.*, b.level + 1 as level
   from etude.tree a 
   left join etude.tree b
   on a._PARENT_ = b._NAME_;
quit;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This code is not working as my new column level only have missing values unless for CL1. I would like to know why it doesn't work or if there is an easier way to do it.

Comment: Doing this in SAS's version of SQL is challenging if not effectively impossible, because it's a fairly basic implementation of SQL.  You could do this in SQL server fairly easily, because of some of the more complex manipulations available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a number of ways.  In your simple layout, where CL# is guaranteed to be in increasing order, this is pretty easy with a temporary array (or a hash table similarly).

```
data tree;
input _NAME_ $ _PARENT_ $ lvl_fin;
datalines;
CL1     .           1
CL2     CL1         2
CL3     CL2         3
CL4     CL1         2
CL5     CL4         3
CL6     CL3         4
CL7     CL5         4
CL8     CL6         5
CL9     CL6         5
;;;;
run;


data tree_fin;
set tree;
array cl[999] _temporary_;
if missing(_parent_) then level=1;
else level = cl[input(compress(_parent_,,'kd'),8.0)]+1;
cl[input(compress(_name_,,'kd'),8.0)]=level;
run;
```

Basically you have an array of the CLs, indexed by the CL number, and you look up the value of the parent and then store the value of the local afterwards.  Temporary arrays are automatically retained, by the way.  This only works if you're guaranteed to always be seeing 'later' nodes after 'parent' nodes; if you ever could see a parent node after a child node, you would have to do this differently or perhaps in two or more passes, but the overall concept is similar.